# Angular with imports - adding resource to controller

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to import a resource to a contoller with es6 imports. 
I've got this resource:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import ngresource from 'angular-resource';

personsResource.$inject = ['$resource'];

function personsResource ($resource) {
   // return $resource ... 
}

export default angular.module('resources.persons', [ngresource])
.service('personsResource', personsResource)
.name
```

When in my module index.js I inject it like this:

```
//other imports
import personsResource from '../../resources/persons.resource';

//console.log(personsResource) returns resources.persons

export default angular.module('app.home', [personsResource])
.config(routing)
.controller('HomeController', HomeController)
.name
```

And my HomeController looks like this:

```
HomeController.$inject = [personsResource];

export default function HomeController(personsResource) {

}
```

And here personsResource is undefined. As I understand, I don't need to import it again in HomeController since I imported it in index.js and passed to HomeController from there.

I actually tried to import it again in HomeController but that didn't help either. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?